# Select from table where value in column A or column B

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a movie database and I've got a link table so I can link movies to their sequels. I've written the below query so I can return the list of sequels where the movie_id is in any of the columns of the link table however I was wondering if there was any better way of doing this as it seems a rather long winded way of going about it?

```
SELECT movie_id, movie_title FROM movies WHERE movie_id in 
    (SELECT movie_1 FROM lk_movies WHERE movie_1 = 1  or  movie_2 = 1 or  movie_3 = 1 or movie_4 = 1 or movie_5 = 1 or movie_6 = 1 or movie_7 = 1 or movie_8 = 1 or movie_9 = 1 or movie_10 = 1)
or movie_id in 
    (SELECT movie_2 FROM lk_movies WHERE movie_1 = 1  or  movie_2 = 1 or  movie_3 = 1 or movie_4 = 1 or movie_5 = 1 or movie_6 = 1 or movie_7 = 1 or movie_8 = 1 or movie_9 = 1 or movie_10 = 1)
or movie_id in 
    (SELECT movie_3 FROM lk_movies WHERE movie_1 = 1  or  movie_2 = 1 or  movie_3 = 1 or movie_4 = 1 or movie_5 = 1 or movie_6 = 1 or movie_7 = 1 or movie_8 = 1 or movie_9 = 1 or movie_10 = 1)
or movie_id in 
    (SELECT movie_4 FROM lk_movies WHERE movie_1 = 1  or  movie_2 = 1 or  movie_3 = 1 or movie_4 = 1 or movie_5 = 1 or movie_6 = 1 or movie_7 = 1 or movie_8 = 1 or movie_9 = 1 or movie_10 = 1)
or movie_id in 
    (SELECT movie_5 FROM lk_movies WHERE movie_1 = 1  or  movie_2 = 1 or  movie_3 = 1 or movie_4 = 1 or movie_5 = 1 or movie_6 = 1 or movie_7 = 1 or movie_8 = 1 or movie_9 = 1 or movie_10 = 1)
or movie_id in 
    (SELECT movie_6 FROM lk_movies WHERE movie_1 = 1  or  movie_2 = 1 or  movie_3 = 1 or movie_4 = 1 or movie_5 = 1 or movie_6 = 1 or movie_7 = 1 or movie_8 = 1 or movie_9 = 1 or movie_10 = 1)
or movie_id in 
    (SELECT movie_7 FROM lk_movies WHERE movie_1 = 1  or  movie_2 = 1 or  movie_3 = 1 or movie_4 = 1 or movie_5 = 1 or movie_6 = 1 or movie_7 = 1 or movie_8 = 1 or movie_9 = 1 or movie_10 = 1)
or movie_id in 
    (SELECT movie_8 FROM lk_movies WHERE movie_1 = 1  or  movie_2 = 1 or  movie_3 = 1 or movie_4 = 1 or movie_5 = 1 or movie_6 = 1 or movie_7 = 1 or movie_8 = 1 or movie_9 = 1 or movie_10 = 1)
or movie_id in 
    (SELECT movie_9 FROM lk_movies WHERE movie_1 = 1  or  movie_2 = 1 or  movie_3 = 1 or movie_4 = 1 or movie_5 = 1 or movie_6 = 1 or movie_7 = 1 or movie_8 = 1 or movie_9 = 1 or movie_10 = 1)
or movie_id in 
    (SELECT movie_10 FROM lk_movies WHERE movie_1 = 1  or  movie_2 = 1 or  movie_3 = 1 or movie_4 = 1 or movie_5 = 1 or movie_6 = 1 or movie_7 = 1 or movie_8 = 1 or movie_9 = 1 or movie_10 = 1);
```

Comment: can you update the table structure

Comment: Normalisation is the key

Comment: Why does `lk_movies` have so many columns?  This sounds like a very bad data structure.  I would suggest that you fix the data model before writing queries on this database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `Mysql` does not support `Unpivot` or `Cross Apply` operator so here is the best I came up with

The sub-query

```
SELECT movie_1 
FROM   lk_movies 
WHERE  movie_1 = 1 
        OR movie_2 = 1 
        OR movie_3 = 1 
        OR movie_4 = 1 
        OR movie_5 = 1 
        OR movie_6 = 1 
        OR movie_7 = 1 
        OR movie_8 = 1 
        OR movie_9 = 1 
        OR movie_10 = 1
```

can be re-written by reversing the `IN` operator

```
SELECT movie_10 
FROM   lk_movies 
WHERE  1 IN( movie_1, movie_2, movie_3, movie_4, 
             movie_5, movie_6, movie_7, movie_8, 
             movie_9, movie_10 )
```

Then use `Union all` instead of multiple `OR` condition here is the full query

```
 SELECT movie_id, 
       movie_title 
FROM   movies 
WHERE  movie_id IN (SELECT movie_1 
                    FROM   lk_movies 
                    WHERE  1 IN( movie_1, movie_2, movie_3, movie_4, 
                                 movie_5, movie_6, movie_7, movie_8, 
                                 movie_9, movie_10 ) 
                    UNION ALL 
                    SELECT movie_2 
                    FROM   lk_movies 
                    WHERE  1 IN( movie_1, movie_2, movie_3, movie_4, 
                                 movie_5, movie_6, movie_7, movie_8, 
                                 movie_9, movie_10 ) 
                    UNION ALL 
                    ...............
                    ...............
                    SELECT movie_10 
                    FROM   lk_movies 
                    WHERE  1 IN( movie_1, movie_2, movie_3, movie_4, 
                                 movie_5, movie_6, movie_7, movie_8, 
                                 movie_9, movie_10 ))
```

Comment: Who benefits from this kind of thing?

Comment: @Strawberry What do you mean by *thing* ?

Comment: Cheers for that. I changed the movies table slightly to add a sequel_ref column allowing me to search on that rather than the movie_id in each column. Ended up with this: (also for Strawberry, this is allowing me to have a list auto-populated on a webpage to display the sequels of the movie record the user is on)
select movie_id, movie_title from movies where sequel_ref in 
 (SELECT reference 
 FROM   lk_movies 
 WHERE  1 IN
  ( movie_1, movie_2, movie_3, movie_4, 
  movie_5, movie_6, movie_7, movie_8, 
  movie_9, movie_10 )
 );

Answer (score 1):

When you create a table with columns that have a number attached, you're almost certainly doing it wrong. Your table is not [normalized properly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

All code below is untested since I don't use mysql. It may have some syntax errors, but you should get the idea.

You could create a tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Movie
| ID | Title   | ... | Sequel |
|  1 | Shrek   | ... | 2      |
|  2 | Shrek 2 | ... | 3      |
|  3 | Shrek 3 | ... | NULL   |
```

That way you'd only know the next sequel, and you'd have to have to follow the `Sequel` column pointing to the next ID until you reach a Movie with a `NULL` in `Sequel`.

```
SELECT A.Titel, B.Titel AS Sequel
FROM Movie A
INNER JOIN Movie B
ON A.Sequel = B.ID
```

To find all sequels in one query, consider a separate table for the sequels. That also removes the limitation on the number of sequels.

```
Movie
| ID | Title    | ... |
|  1 | Shrek    | ... |
|  2 | Shrek 2  | ... |
|  3 | Shrek 3  | ... |
```

and

```
Sequel
| Movie_ID | Sequel_ID |
|        1 |         2 | 
|        1 |         3 |
|        2 |         3 |
```

Then you can select from that

```
SELECT Movie.Titel 
FROM Movie 
INNER JOIN Sequel
ON Movie.Movie_ID = Sequel.Sequel_ID
INNER JOIN Movie S
ON Sequel.Sequel_ID = S.Movie_ID
```

The drawback here is that you duplicate information, i.e., you need to store for Shrek that there is Shrek 2 and Shrek 3 as sequels, and for Shrek 2 you duplicate the fact that Shrek 3 is a sequel of Shrek 2. Unless, of course, you always want to only search from the very first movie.

Note the corner case for Highlander, which cannot have sequels. There can be only one.